# CodeIgniter 2.0 always redirected to welcome controller when set uri_protocol as AUTO

Tags: php, codeigniter, configuration, codeigniter-2

I just set up a development environment using CodeIgniter 2.0 and in config I leave the `uri_protocol` as

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

But my problem is all Controller/Action request send to the welcome controller. I checked this again by changing the `uri_protocol` to `QUERY_STRING` and it works fine for me. Why is this always redirected to welcome controller when using `uri_protocol` as `AUTO`?

Comment: We should see some code.

Comment: you mean the default controller? or it goes to the welcome controller no matter what you put in the uri?

Comment: I have this same problem. Yes, it goes to the default controller no matter what we put in the URL. There's not really any code to speak of: it's just a plain old CodeIgniter setup. What would we show you - the entire system?

Answer (score 2):

'AUTO' option actualy tries the possible option in a certain order which may not be suitable to system you are working on.  You should test each of the possible options to see which one suits your system. It happened to me on a customer server (windows server i guess).

Possible options listed as comment above the option line.

```
'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
```